# Can't play bluffing game like Avalon or Were

Tags: one-night-werewolf, the-resistance-avalon

First, I've no problem with my logic. I can play strategy games, coding.

But I don't know why when it's come to bluffing game like Avalon or Werewolf, My brain is dead.

I just don't get what they talking about during game.
Who is bluffing who for what?

How can I adjust my mind to be able to play these games properly?
What am I missing? Am I really alone who can't play the game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll ignore One Night Werewolf for now and focus on Avalon and more typical mafia games. To begin with, something that you may be overthinking:

**Not everyone is expected to bluff or lie.**

For the basic villager or knight, there's no harm in being wholly open and honest. You want people to believe you are a villager which is true. You aren't privy to any information that you don't want people to know (the one thing you're sure of is that you're a good guy). Be open and honest about suspicions. Choose succeed for every mission. Worst case scenario, you make an honest mistake.

**So when does someone lie?**

First, when they're the bad guys. The bad guys definitely don't want anyone to know their role since if people knew they'd be killed (werewolf) or never taken on missions. This means pretending to be a good guy.

This is where the bluffing comes in. Minions know the identity of minions. Now, you probably* don't want to out your fellow minion and you definitely don't want to out yourself. This means any "suspicions" you have will be lies to draw attention away from you.

Second, when you're powerful. Merlin, for example, knows the identities of all the minions, but his team loses the game if he is identified. This means a difficult balance between using that information and remaining hidden. I won't go into detail here- there's at least one question that covers this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

The bluffing/lying stems from the major premise of most of these games: *an uninformed majority against an informed minority.*

If everyone knew the teams, the majority would just win every vote (and every game). So the minority needs to lie, blend in, etc.

Comment: I don't see any reason to think the OP didn't already understand that.

Comment: "Who is bluffing who (sic) for what?" made me think that he is missing something more or less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

These are hidden information games so one person is trying to work against the group without anyone catching them.  It is more like a game of poker than standard strategy game since you are looking for the unusual behavior.  It is a very different type of game because 90% of the players are working towards one goal while the other players are trying to fake it enough not to be caught, which isn't normally for most games where everyone is working toward the same goal and doesn't need to hide their intentions.  Think of playing a strategy game where each player's final goal was hidden, it would be a much different game at that point since you don't know exactly what everyone is trying to do to win.